# Javascript: Regex to replace translate3d string from style string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace alla the occurences of the string `translate3d(-640px, 0px, 0px);` with `translate(-640px)`.

This is what I am doing:

```
var string = "width: 960px; height: 548px; transition: 0s; -webkit-transition: 0s; transform: translate3d(-640px, 0px, 0px); -webkit-transform: translate3d(-640px, 0px, 0px);";
var regExp = //; //I am not able to create this one
var matches = regExp.exec(string);
var left = matches[1]; //this will give the value -640px
var newstring = string.replace('translate3d('+left+', 0px, 0px)', 'translate('+left+')');
```

There are 2 problems:

1. I cannot create the right regex to only extract the left value.
2. The .replace() method only replace one occurence of the string, while I need to replace them all.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
var newstring = string.replace(/translate3d\(([^,]+)[^)]*\)/g, 'translate($1)');
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pV0cQ9/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
translate3d\(([^,]+),\s*0[^,1-9]*,\s*0[^)1-9]*\)
```

Replace with `translate($1)`.

This only replaces occurences of `translated3d` if the 2nd and 3rd values are 0. (Regardless of unit - `0px`, `0cm`, you name it.)

[regex101 demo.](https://regex101.com/r/mA8hC0/1)